# Can't observe speedup on parallel Haskell code but profiling indicates otherwise

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, profiling, ghc

I wrote a minimal example trying to parallelize some computation in Haskell. I basically tried to map some trig functions onto a long list by

1. split the list in half
2. evaluate the two halves in parallel
3. concatenate them
4. fold the list

My code:

```hs
-- in file par.hs

module Par where

import Control.Parallel
import Data.List

parmap f l = let
    halflen = floor $ (realToFrac $ length l) / 2
    half1 = take halflen l
    half2 = drop halflen l
    mapped1 = map f half1
    mapped2 = map f half2
    in mapped1 `par` (mapped2 `pseq` mapped1 ++ mapped2)

forceEval x = sin x + cos x - tan x + sin(3*x) - cos(2*x)

runMap :: Double
runMap = foldl' (+) 0.0 $ parmap forceEval [0.0..2000000.0]

main = do
    putStrLn $ show runMap
```

I compiled it with `ghc -prof -fprof-auto -rtsopts -threaded par.hs`

I ran it with `./par +RTS -p -N?` where `?` is number of processors

I then looked at the generated `par.prof` file.

---

Below are a couple of profiling outputs I got. I ran and profiled multiple times, so I'm pretty sure these numbers were not outliers.

Running with `-N1` gave me:

```
    Tue May  7 23:20 2019 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       par +RTS -N1 -p -RTS

    total time  =        1.20 secs   (1200 ticks @ 1000 us, 1 processor)
    total alloc = 1,936,132,144 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE    SRC                   %time %alloc

forceEval     Main      par.hs:28:1-57         75.8   60.3
runMap        Main      par.hs:31:1-59         17.5   19.0
parmap'       Main      par.hs:(6,1)-(12,56)    3.2   14.9
parmap'.half1 Main      par.hs:8:5-26           2.3    5.8
parmap'.half2 Main      par.hs:9:5-26           1.1    0.0
```

Running with `-N2` (note how the profile indicates a more than a 2x speedup?):

```
    Tue May  7 23:24 2019 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       par +RTS -N2 -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.36 secs   (725 ticks @ 1000 us, 2 processors)
    total alloc = 1,936,149,368 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE    SRC                   %time %alloc

forceEval     Main      par.hs:28:1-57         70.6   60.3
runMap        Main      par.hs:31:1-59         19.3   19.0
parmap'       Main      par.hs:(6,1)-(12,56)    4.3   14.9
parmap'.half1 Main      par.hs:8:5-26           3.3    5.8
parmap'.half2 Main      par.hs:9:5-26           1.7    0.0
```

Running with `-N4` (note the slight more speedup compared to `-N2`):

```
    Tue May  7 23:25 2019 Time and Allocation Profiling Report  (Final)

       par +RTS -N4 -p -RTS

    total time  =        0.27 secs   (1098 ticks @ 1000 us, 4 processors)
    total alloc = 1,936,183,704 bytes  (excludes profiling overheads)

COST CENTRE   MODULE    SRC                   %time %alloc

forceEval     Main      par.hs:28:1-57         71.5   60.3
runMap        Main      par.hs:31:1-59         19.3   19.0
parmap'       Main      par.hs:(6,1)-(12,56)    3.8   14.9
parmap'.half1 Main      par.hs:8:5-26           3.6    5.8
parmap'.half2 Main      par.hs:9:5-26           1.2    0.0
```

---

I expected to see *some* speedup when running on two processors, but no additional speedup if I run on more processors. But I couldn't visually observe any speedup at all, yet the GHC profiles above told me that there was a speed up - an unrealistically good one, plus additional speedup if I use more than two processors?

In fact in another program where I attempted to parallelize computation, I was compiling and profiling using stack, and observed such similar false speedup as well.

I'd really appreciate if someone could explain to me what went on: Is this the right way of writing parallel Haskell code? Why could running with 4 cores be helpful in runtime if I only had two parts to evaluate in parallel? Or did I just misinterpret the profiling output?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: How are you determining that there isn’t any speedup?

Answer (score 1):

When `par` compute it's first argument it just force top level node to compute, but it can still refer to some lazy computation.

If you change it to

```
import Control.Parallel
import Data.List

parmap f a l = let
    halflen = floor $ (realToFrac $ length l) / 2
    half1 = take halflen l
    half2 = drop halflen l
    mapped1 = map f half1
    mapped2 = map f half2
    agg1 = a mapped1
    agg2 = a mapped2
    in agg1 `par` agg2 `pseq` a [agg1, agg2] 

forceEval x = sin x + cos x - tan x + sin(3*x) - cos(2*x)                   

runMap :: Double
runMap = parmap forceEval (foldl' (+) 0.0) [0.0..20000000.0]

main = do
    putStrLn $ show runMap
```

You will see speedup when switch from one thread

```
time ./f +RTS -N1
-4615093.834471449

real    0m13.077s
user    0m12.333s
sys 0m0.744s
```

to two thread

```
time ./f +RTS -N2
-4615093.834471449

real    0m9.057s
user    0m14.512s
sys 0m2.170s
```

In my example `agg1` and `agg2` is primitive values and it is easier to force their computation.

**Alternative**

You can use `rnf` from `Control.DeepSeq` to force whole list to be computed.

```
import Control.Parallel 
import Control.DeepSeq
import Data.List

parmap f l = let
    halflen = floor $ (realToFrac $ length l) / 2
    half1 = take halflen l
    half2 = drop halflen l
    mapped1 = map f half1
    mapped2 = map f half2
    in (rnf mapped1) `par` (rnf mapped2) `pseq` (mapped1 ++ mapped2)

forceEval x = sin x + cos x - tan x + sin(3*x) - cos(2*x)

runMap :: Double
runMap = foldl' (+) 0.0 $ parmap forceEval [0.0..20000000.0]

main = do
    putStrLn $ show runMap
```

And see performance improvement.

One thread

```
time ./f2 +RTS -N1
-4615093.83447202

real    0m15.241s
user    0m14.261s
sys 0m0.980s
```

Two threads

```
time ./f2 +RTS -N2
-4615093.83447202

real    0m11.640s
user    0m17.092s
sys 0m3.178s
```